# Running Dataproc workflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, google-workflows

I'm looking to use Dataproc workflows to run sequential Spark jobs.

Basing on [docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/workflows/using-workflows) it is required to:

1. Create a workflow
2. Add jobs to the workflow by their names
3. Start the workflow

In order to add a job to the workflow, you need to know the ID of that job. And thus you need to submit the job. But once all jobs are submitted how to suspend them, add to the workflow and then run the workflow with those jobs?

Answer (score 0):

All jobs run concurrently unless you specify one or more job dependencies. You will be the one to provide a `step-id` for each job.

**Examples:**

Add *Hadoop* job "*foo*" to the "*my-workflow*" template.

```
gcloud dataproc workflow-templates add-job hadoop \
    --region=[region] \
    --step-id=foo \
    --workflow-template=my-workflow \
    -- [space separated job args]
```

Add job "*bar*" to the "*my-workflow*" template, which will be run after workflow job "*foo*" has completed successfully.

```
> gcloud dataproc workflow-templates add-job [job-type] \
>     --region=[region] \
>     --step-id=bar \
>     --start-after=foo \
>     --workflow-template=my-workflow \
>     -- [space separated job args]
```

Notice the parameter `--start-after` which indicates that the job you specify will be run after that workflow job. In this manner, you can run the Spark jobs sequentially.